# PowerShell Script: need the program to specify where content was found

Tags: powershell

```
$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerShell Script")
$keyword = read-host "Keyword:"
$info = get-content c:\users\dell\desktop\urls.txt

foreach ($i in $info) {
    $output = ""
    $output = $webClient.DownloadString($i)

    if ($output -like "*$keyword*") {
        $b = Get-Date
        $ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::Ok
        $MessageboxTitle = “Open Source Information Collection”
        $Messageboxbody = "Detected the keyword $keyword at $b"
        $MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Asterisk
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($Messageboxbody,$MessageboxTitle,$ButtonType,$messageicon)
    }

}
```

The code does gets the content from various websites listed in the urls.txt file, and searches for a specific keyword.

If the keyword is found, the user is notified.

However, what I am missing, is for the program to not only notify the user that a keyword was found to match the content, but also to say which website the content that matches with the keyword has originated from.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the URL you are looking for is located in $i.

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($Messageboxbody,$MessageboxTitle,$ButtonType,$messageicon,$i)
```

From your code, you are assigning $i from $info so $i should be the single URL that then gets checked for the keyword.

Having not run the code and seen the formatting, you may need to add $i to $messageboxbody. For example

```
$Messageboxbody = "Detected the keyword $keyword at $b from URL $i"
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks, Tim.